# MSBuild Annoyances (or blatant ignorance on my part)

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

In reworking our deployment process I moved over to using an MSBuild project in place of our existing batch files.  All of the major elements are in place, and I was looking to cut out a step or two but ran into a snag.

I'm creating a property called OutputPath using the CombinePath task, and, while I can access it with no issues after it has been created I'm at a loss as for how to use it to my advantage.  Consider:

```
<CombinePath BasePath ="$(DeployFolderRoot)" Paths ="$(DeployReleaseFolder)$(ReleaseFolderFormatted)" >
  <Output TaskParameter ="CombinedPaths" ItemName ="OutputFolder"/>
</CombinePath>

<MakeDir Directories="@(OutputFolder)" />
<MakeDir Directories="@(OutputFolder)\Foo" />
<MakeDir Directories="@(OutputFolder)\Bar" />
```

Commands 2 and 3 fail because I'm referencing an array and attempting to concatenate with a string.  Creating a property and assigning it @(OutputFolder) simply results in another item group, not a property I can reference with the $ accessor.  I do have an ugly workaround but I'd love to clear this up somewhat.

Thanks,

-Jose

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure of the answer exactly but here is an idea:

```
<CombinePath BasePath ="$(DeployFolderRoot)" Paths ="$(DeployReleaseFolder)$(ReleaseFolderFormatted)" >
  <Output TaskParameter ="CombinedPaths" ItemName ="OutputFolder"/>
</CombinePath>

<OutputFolder Include="$(DeployFolderRoot)$(DeployReleaseFolder)$(ReleaseFolderFormatted)\Foo" /> 
<OutputFolder Include="$(DeployFolderRoot)$(DeployReleaseFolder)$(ReleaseFolderFormatted)\Bar" />

<MakeDir Directories="@(OutputFolder)" />
```

Essentially, if you create OutputFolder items with the path they will just be appended to the list. This would have to be in an  element btw, and you have to use Include="".

Answer (score 1):

dOh! Definitely ignorance, used the wrong attribute on the Output element.

```
<CombinePath BasePath ="$(DeployFolderRoot)" Paths ="$(DeployReleaseFolder)$(ReleaseFolderFormatted)" >
  <Output TaskParameter ="CombinedPaths" PropertyName="OutputFolder"/>
</CombinePath>

<MakeDir Directories="$(OutputFolder)" />
<MakeDir Directories="$(OutputFolder)\Foo" />
<MakeDir Directories="$(OutputFolder)\Bar" />
```